# форма поиска bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, get

Здравствуйте, у меня есть бутстраповская форма поиска:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 180px;">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search-input">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn" id="srchbtn" type="btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки поиска переходило не на `/?search=test`, а на `/search/test`? P.S. Паттерн для замены гет запроса в .htaccess уже прописан.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.assign('/search/test');
        })
```